# How to 'trigger' chef-solo and get callback/report?

Tags: deployment, web, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm thinking to use Chef-Solo as a PaaS orchestrator.

I'll have my own dashboard which will generate recipes and my nodes will pull from them. I know I can do that by using :

```
chef-solo -i <interval>
```

But, if i'd like to add more and more attributes; like having a list of virtualhosts or mysql users to deploy. I don't know how I can achieve this.

I'm looking for your ideas; I 'think' engineyard is using chef to deploy 'on demand' php, node .js apps; how did they achieve this ?

How not to re-execute an app deployment if that one has already been deployed

On first run i'll have :

```
"websites" : {
     "site1": { "username": "dave", "password": "password123" }
},
```

And then, when a new site is created the attributes would become :

```
"websites" : {
     "site1": { "username": "dave", "password": "password123" }
     "site2": { "username": "bob", "password": "password123" }
}
```

etc.

And how to get report on what chef-solo is doing ?

Any ingenious idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Add chef-server to your PAAS stack and use knife to push your receipes there. Knife can also be used to initially provision nodes in your PAAS, taking care of installing the chef client (configured to talk to your chef server).

The chef solo client is useful for simple use cases, but <strike>doesn't really scale</strike> will require additional supporting code for items like monitoring/reporting (your question) and when you move to more complex multi-tier deployment scenarios.

Comment: I'll try to 'avoid' using chef-server; joyent use chef-solo and don't tell me it "doesn't really scale" :) other ideas on my actual concern ?

Comment: @Disco Perhaps scaling is the wrong word. My point is that you'll end up designing a lot of functionality that duplicates what chef-server provides. Up to you, good luck!